# Massive Storage Being Used

Tags: storage

I have a 16GB Galaxy S3 with a 64GB SD Card. However, it appears that files have been saving to my device and not the external card. I only have 4 Gigs left of the 16. Is there any app that can "take all internal storage and move them to SD Card"? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: As a side-note: AFAIK, you had less than 8 GB to start with (as those "16 GB" don't refer to the storage available to the user, but rather the overall storage, and about half of it is reserved for the ROM). Considering that, does your assumption still hold?

Comment: Ooh, yeah I know that. But I still don't like holding files to internal unless they are software. I guess so, I'd still prefer to transfer all data between storsge devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try moving apps installed in internal memory to sd card by long pressing on the desired app from the app drawer and dragging it up to the app info panel ,scroll down and there you may find the "Move to SD card" option. However afaik you cannot move apps to SD on the s3 unless rooted. You got to manage your files and apps using the 11 GB available or else root your device.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can move apps to external on a sgs3.? I had this phone previously and used app2sd no problem simply download it from Google play store, then once you open up the app it will tell you which apps can be moved to the external sd card. you can download it for free from the Google play store. 
https://play.google.com/store?hl=en_GB

Comment: Your answer is very short, care to re-edit your answer to include more info such as how to get it to work for the benefit of the OP's question, rather than "I had this *device* previously and .... "